# Get maximum value of number of keys (hlen) for hashes that match given pattern in Redis

Tags: mysql, hash, redis, nosql

I have many records that start with the pattern as shown below:

`user:8d6120be2e7247e49545502092c389fd` and

`user:000935dc3bb16bd2e0de50988751acfd`

Though the hash represent user object, one hash may have more keys than the other. Say if user is a Manager then he may have few additional keys like Reportees, Benifits etc., Without actually looking into all the records is there a way to know the maximum number of keys in any hash? I am in the process of converting the Redis structure in to Relational schema and this gives me an idea on what all columns should be present.

Comment: No, you'll need to HLEN each key.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [HLEN](http://redis.io/commands/HLEN) if your `user:<hash>` key is HSET. The most of data structures in redis have the way to get they len:

- [LLEN](http://redis.io/commands/smembers) in LIST
- [SMEMBERS](http://redis.io/commands/smembers) in SET
- [ZCARD](http://redis.io/commands/zcard) in SORTED SET

Comment: `SCARD` is for set length.

Comment: No, Ben, SCARD returns the sorted set cardinality (number of elements) of the sorted set stored at key.